# Pagination with Search Filter in CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter

When I search a keyword and paginate it, it returns data that matches the like query in the database.

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning

Message: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable

Filename: admin/view_member.php

Line Number: 105

Backtrace:

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\cms_new\application\views\admin\view_member.php
Line: 105
Function: _error_handler

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\cms_new\application\controllers\admin\Member.php
Line: 63
Function: view

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\cms_new\index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once

MY Controller

```
$search = ($this->input->post("member_name"))? $this->input->post("member_name") : "NIL";

        $search = ($this->uri->segment(3)) ? $this->uri->segment(3) : $search;

        // pagination settings
        $config = array();
        $config['base_url'] = site_url("admin/member/index/$search");
        $config['total_rows'] = $this->Model_member->record_count($search);
        $config['per_page'] = "3";
        $config["uri_segment"] = 4;
        $choice = $config["total_rows"]/$config["per_page"];
        $config["num_links"] = floor($choice);

        // integrate bootstrap pagination
        $config['full_tag_open'] = '<ul class="pagination">';
        $config['full_tag_close'] = '</ul>';
        $config['first_link'] = false;
        $config['last_link'] = false;
        $config['first_tag_open'] = '<li>';
        $config['first_tag_close'] = '</li>';
        $config['prev_link'] = 'Prev';
        $config['prev_tag_open'] = '<li class="prev">';
        $config['prev_tag_close'] = '</li>';
        $config['next_link'] = 'Next';
        $config['next_tag_open'] = '<li>';
        $config['next_tag_close'] = '</li>';
        $config['last_tag_open'] = '<li>';
        $config['last_tag_close'] = '</li>';
        $config['cur_tag_open'] = '<li class="active"><a href="#">';
        $config['cur_tag_close'] = '</a></li>';
        $config['num_tag_open'] = '<li>';
        $config['num_tag_close'] = '</li>';
        $this->pagination->initialize($config);

        $data['page'] = ($this->uri->segment(4)) ? $this->uri->segment(4) : 0;
        // get books list
        $data['users'] = $this->Model_member->fetch_data($config['per_page'], $data['page'], $search);

        $data['pagination'] = $this->pagination->create_links();


        $this->load->view('admin/view_header',$data);
        $this->load->view('admin/view_member',$data);
        $this->load->view('admin/view_footer');
```

My Model

```
function fetch_data($limit, $start, $st = NULL)
    {
        if($st == "NIL")
            $st = "";
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('tbl_member');
        $this->db->like('member_name', $st);
        $this->db->or_like('member_email', $st);
        $this->db->limit($limit, $start);
        $query = $this->db->get();

                if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {

                //var_dump($query->result());

                foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
                $data[] = $row;
            }

        //print_r($query);
        return $data;
        }

        if ($query->num_rows() == 0) {

            $this->session->set_flashdata('recoard','<div class="alert alert-danger text-center">Record Not Found! </div>');
        }

        return false;
    }
    
    function record_count($st = NULL)
    {
        if($st == "NIL")
            $st = "";

        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('tbl_member');

        $this->db->like('member_name', $st);
        $this->db->or_like('member_email', $st);

        $query = $this->db->get();

        return $query->num_rows();

        var_dump($query->num_rows());
    }
```

My View

```
<?php
                              $user = count($users);

                              var_dump($user);

                               for ($i = 0; $i < $user; ++$i) { 


                              if(! $users ){
                          
                                // Faild Message
                                 echo $this->session->flashdata('recoard');
                                 }

                                else {

                              ?>

                              <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="text-center"><img class="rounded-circle img-fluid avatar-40" src="<?php echo base_url();; ?>public/uploads/<?php echo $users[$i]->member_photo; ?>" alt="profile"></td>
                                    <td><?php echo $users[$i]->member_name; ?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo $users[$i]->member_email; ?><br>
                                      <?php echo $users[$i]->member_mobile; ?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo $users[$i]->member_city; ?><br>
                                      <?php echo $users[$i]->member_state; ?><br>
                                      <?php echo $users[$i]->member_country; ?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo $users[$i]->member_address; ?></td>
                                    <td>
                                      <?php 
                                      if($users[$i]->member_access == 1) 
                                      {
                                        echo '<span class="badge iq-bg-primary">Active</span></td>';
                                      }
                                      else 
                                      {
                                        echo '<span class="badge iq-bg-warning">Inactive</span></td>';
                                      }
                                      ?>
                                      </td>
                                        
                                        <td>
                                          <div class="flex align-items-center list-user-action">
                                             <a data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="" data-original-title="Change Status" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>admin/member/change_status/<?php echo $users[$i]->member_id; ?>" onClick="return confirm('Are you sure?');"><i class="ri-user-add-line"></i></a>

                                             <a data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="" data-original-title="Edit" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>admin/member/edit/<?php echo $users[$i]->member_id; ?>"><i class="ri-pencil-line"></i></a>

                                             <a data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="" data-original-title="Delete" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>admin/member/delete/<?php $users[$i]->member_id; ?>" onClick="return confirm('Are you sure?');"><i class="iq-bg-danger ri-delete-bin-line"></i></a>
                                          </div>
                                       </td>
                                    </tr>
                               
                              </tbody>
                              <?php } } ?>
```

Comment: What version of PHP are you using? As of PHP 7.2 method count will throw an error if you try to use it on an unset variable.

Answer (score 0):

you seem to not be returning an array to count & loop over, this is why you have the warning.

Also you have the failed message inside your loop that will make more errors later on.
Hope this helps & works for you

```
<?php
if (!$users || !is_array($users)) {
  // Faild Message
  echo $this->session->flashdata('recoard');
} else {
  foreach ($users as $user) { ?>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td class="text-center"><img class="rounded-circle img-fluid avatar-40" src="<?php echo base_url("public/uploads/"); ?><?php echo $user->member_photo; ?>" alt="profile"></td>
        <td><?php echo $user->member_name; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $user->member_email; ?><br>
          <?php echo $user->member_mobile; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $user->member_city; ?><br>
          <?php echo $user->member_state; ?><br>
          <?php echo $user->member_country; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $user->member_address; ?></td>
        <td>
          <?php
          if ($user->member_access == 1) {
            echo '<span class="badge iq-bg-primary">Active</span></td>';
          } else {
            echo '<span class="badge iq-bg-warning">Inactive</span></td>';
          }
          ?>
        </td>

        <td>
          <div class="flex align-items-center list-user-action">
            <a data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="" data-original-title="Change Status" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>admin/member/change_status/<?php echo $user->member_id; ?>" onClick="return confirm('Are you sure?');"><i class="ri-user-add-line"></i></a>

            <a data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="" data-original-title="Edit" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>admin/member/edit/<?php echo $user->member_id; ?>"><i class="ri-pencil-line"></i></a>

            <a data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="" data-original-title="Delete" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>admin/member/delete/<?php $user->member_id; ?>" onClick="return confirm('Are you sure?');"><i class="iq-bg-danger ri-delete-bin-line"></i></a>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>

    </tbody>
<?php }
} ?>
```